# How to get the first key (not value) of immutable.js map?

Tags: immutable.js

How to get the first key (not value) of immutable.js map?

basically  `myMap.first()` will return the value, but I am interested in the key...

I can do a forEach and store first, but must be a better way!

didn't see it in the docs, prob missing it... :/

tx

Sean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do this -

`var firstKey = map.keySeq().first();`

Explanation - Get me a lazy sequence of keys of this map, then resolve the first key. Alternatively you can use `keys()` method which returns plain old ES6 iterator. It will be less performant though.

Comment: Not sure about the triviality and why would you want the first key. If your use case is about order of entries in the map, you can use OrderedMap. Also seq should perform better as it isn't operated on all items.